# 'As the dot on the i' used as an expression

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Since I am not a native speaker, I would like to know whether you use such an expression *'as the dot on the i'*? If not, which expression could be similar?

For example, after a series of unfortunate events, the last unfortunate event was *'as the dot on the i'*.

I know that there is *'dot the i's and cross the t's'*, but that has a different meaning.

Comment: No, it's not an expression.  An equivalent would be *"The straw that broke the camel's back"* or, similarly, *"the last straw"*, among various others.

Comment: Perhaps "the icing on the cake"

Comment: @RonJensen  Definitely not the icing on the cake! That's the best bit. OP is referring to mishaps.

Comment: You can use it as the worst bit, ironically. “I had just the worst day.   I twisted my ankle getting into bed; that was the icing on the cake.”

Comment: @whiskeychief - We can use it that way, and some probably do. But others might characterize that as a minor misuse of the expression. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/icing-on-the-cake) defines that idiom to mean _something that makes a good situation even better_ or _an unexpected additional good thing_. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+icing+on+the+cake) says: _An additional benefit or positive aspect to something that is already considered positive or beneficial._ (I'm not trying to be pedantic; I just think this is good to point out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express something negative in the sense of "another indignity" there is **the final insult**.

Although I couldn't find a good reference to a dictionary definition of the term, it's something I commonly hear.

There are many examples of its use. All bold text in the following is my own emphasis.

["The Final Insult: A Lost Domain"](https://www.wired.com/2002/11/the-final-insult-a-lost-domain/) by Paul Boutin:

> They lost their jobs, their careers, even their apartments in the Internet bust. But **the final insult** for many Web workers is learning that somewhere in the churn of e-mail addresses and phone numbers from the dot-com bust, they've lost their personal domains as well.

[*Pushing the Pencil*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RT1RAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22the%20final%20insult%22%20meaning&source=bl&ots=UaP3xfDr2T&sig=ACfU3U0vnTuITQOa8JarYkxPOk0dqCXvxg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi20uzbpo7lAhVlTt8KHew0BkcQ6AEwH3oECGEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20final%20insult%22%20meaning&f=false) by Donald Wilcox Thomas:

> But now comes **the final insult**: teachers are to be paid according to their "performance," meaning what they are able to produce in the minds of their students. Now they are to be held suddenly "accountable," meaning that their teaching is to be translated into numbers that are duly extracted from certain tests designed to weigh and measure the quality of human thought, presuming that such tests actually exist. It will be like piece work on earns in a factory based on the number of widgets produced.

[*Dark Angel*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=vLwYRNiQpAYC&pg=PT60&lpg=PT60&dq=%22the%20final%20insult%22%20meaning&source=bl&ots=o837Zykj5N&sig=ACfU3U227X2zjtucL18zt8Stk4LBrSOXnw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi20uzbpo7lAhVlTt8KHew0BkcQ6AEwJHoECGIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20final%20insult%22%20meaning&f=false) by Lynne Graham:

> '*I* made all the allowances, *I* did all the giving, and at the end of the day you still let me down. You let a woolly-headed old man play ducks and drakes with my money … **the final insult** for me has to be the sight of that bloody tarpaulin on the roof!'

["What counts as a genocide"](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2015/04/23/what-counts-as-a-genocide) by H.J. at The Economist:

> The “g-word” has considerable power. If mass slaughter is recognised as genocide when it is happening, it is harder for outside forces to sit idly by. When it is over, official recognition that it was genocide can give the survivors some grim satisfaction. But when that recognition is withheld, whether because of a technicality or political expediency, it can feel like **the final insult**. And some human-rights activists and legal scholars feel that genocide’s status as the “crime of crimes” sometimes overshadows the horror of other crimes against humanity.

---

In a slightly different sense—one that speaks more to a reaction of cynical defeat (or possibly of anger) than of simply the event itself, there is [**the last straw**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last%20straw), as suggested in a comment under the question.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : the last of a series (as of events or indignities) that brings one beyond the point of endurance
>   //  But at 84, widowed and slowing down, the *last straw* for my mother was an errant bat in the bedroom at midnight.
>   — Lee Woodruff, *San Diego Union-Tribune*, "A summer vacation caregiver," 8 Aug. 2019